# Using Github for pypi packge versioning

Tags: python, git, github, pip, pypi

I am trying to find a way to use my Github repo tags for versioning of my package, which should be available for download using something like pip.
The problem is every time I update the package version I have to upload the contents to pypi.
Is there any way to just set the donwload url in pypi point to my github repo, So that when I do something like
`pip install -I MySQL_python==1.2.2` and it just install that form the git tag `1.2.2`, without me having to upload the version to pypi.

**EDIT**:(I was not clear enough)

I know about the `pip install git+git://blabal` way
 I am looking for something like I tell pypi that my package is at `github.com/bla.git`
 and the user does pip install bla==1.2 and pip install that from github (with version as tag)
 Something like vundle for vim

Answer (score 1):

You could install like this:

```
pip install -e git+<repo address>@<ref>#egg=<egg name>
```

where ref could be a commit id, tag name or branch name.

[Read the docs](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#git).